# Get URL's parameters of HTTP request angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I trying to get URL's parameters of a HTTP frame ("GET http://www.quatuoradbd.com/Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8 HTTP1.1 Host: www.quatuoradbd.com")

To test, I use Fiddler software. 
So I send this frame : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6MTA.png)

Then I get this response : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXAIa.png) that is the index.html of my Angular web site plus many bundles between  balise whereas I want to access to Reception route and not to index.html

Furthermore, I receive the result that says that everything is fine with the code 200 : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrdZP.png)

However, I don't understand why my frame does not reach the destination (/Reception) so that I could get my URL parameters, which are ID and Voltage.

To getting URL's parameters my code is the following and it works because when I write this directly into chrome "http://www.quatuoradbd.com/Reception?ID=00-80-00-00-00-00-d5-ef&Voltage=8" (see picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/osInH.png), my parameters are saved into my database :

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params);
    this.device_id = params.get('ID');
    this.Voltage = params.get('Voltage');
    console.log(this.device_id);
    console.log(this.Voltage);
    });
```

Comment: There's no problem in how you're dealing with the query Params. Have you set up your routes for 'reception' page?

Answer (score 0):

I think my route for reception is fine right?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccueilComponent } from './accueil/accueil.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { InconnuComponent } from './inconnu/inconnu.component';
import { ClientsComponent } from './clients/clients.component';
import { ProjetsComponent } from './projets/projets.component';
import { HistoireComponent } from './histoire/histoire.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';
import { IdentificationComponent } from './identification/identification.component';
import { ConfirmationCompteComponent } from './confirmation-compte/confirmation-compte.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import { GraphiquesComponent } from './graphiques/graphiques.component';
import { ReceptionComponent } from './reception/reception.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/Accueil', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'ConfirmationCompte/:email', component: ConfirmationCompteComponent },
{ path: 'Graphiques/:id', component: GraphiquesComponent },
{ path: 'Accueil', component: AccueilComponent },
{ path: 'Projets', component: ProjetsComponent },
{ path: 'Clients', component: ClientsComponent },
{ path: 'Histoire', component: HistoireComponent },
{ path: 'Inscription', component: InscriptionComponent },
{ path: 'Identification', component: IdentificationComponent },
{ path: 'Reception', component: ReceptionComponent },
{ path: 'Map', component: MapComponent },
{ path: '**', component: InconnuComponent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```